# Improving Arguelles, a beamer theme, circumventing the use of TikZ in background definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, backgrounds, themes

I found a very neat `beamer` theme (`Arguelles`, https://github.com/piazzai/arguelles) however there are three things that I believe are troublesome with the theme. I am trying to improve them but I am finding myself short of the required knowledge in the `beamer` class and `LaTeX` in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question is about circumventing the use of TikZ to define every frame's background. The background of each slide is defined using a `TikZ` picture, recomputed for every slide. This is not bothering for short presentations with few other `TikZ` figures, but it becomes quite a problem once one tries to write long presentations with many `TikZ` figures, where the use of the `TikZ` library `externalize` would be beneficial. Again, I can circumvent this by replacing lines 62-69 of `beamerinnerthemeArguelles.sty` by `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=structure.bg}`, but it removes the bottom black bar and seems to break other things such as standout slides. The question is then: how to rewrite the `background` specification in `beamerinnerthemeArguelles.sty` so that it produces the same output, without using `TikZ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a dark background colour and then overpaint all frames with tikz, I would use a light colour and add the small black stripe as a footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Arguelles}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=structure.bg}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \color{structure.fg}%
  \rule{\paperwidth}{.01\paperheight}
}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@titlepage{%
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=structure.fg}
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@titlepage}}{}

% standout frame
\define@key{beamerframe}{standout}[true]{
 \booltrue{Arguelles@standout}
 \begingroup
 \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=structure.fg}
 \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
 \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1.25fill\relax%
 \color{structure.bg}
 \large
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[standout]
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That makes much more sense indeed, but for some reason it makes a complete blank slide for the title slide (when using the ```plain``` option) and the ```standout``` slides are "normal slides" with no text. Did you also modify the inner theme?

Comment: You need to remove the tikz stuff: `%% background
%\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{
% \setbeamertemplate{background}{
%  \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
%   \ifnum\thepage>1\relax
%    \fill[structure.bg] (0,.01\paperheight) rectangle (\paperwidth,.99\paperheight);
%   \fi
%  \end{tikzpicture}
% }
%}`

Comment: Ah I see. Then there is one last caveat. The title page should not have a progress bar. The way this was done before was by calling ```\frame[plain]{\titlepage}```. If I do that I get a blank page. I could call ```\frame{\titlepage}```, but then it shows the progress bar.

Comment: I have found a way to remove it using ```\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}``` for the whole title frame. It feels hack-ish but it works.